# Unable to use angularfirebase2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using angularfirebase2 with the latest version `^5.0.0-rc.10` and my project configuration:

```
`@angular/cli: 1.4.1
node: 8.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4`
```

But while compiling the project it throws an error :

> E:/Prashant/UserManagement/Farmer Angular/kalpavriksha-angular-v4/node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts (2,42): Module '"E:/Prashant/UserManagement/Farmer Angular/kalpavriksha-angular-v4/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.

After update firebase version to `^5.0.4` getting this error:

> Metadata version mismatch for module E:/Prashant/UserManagement/Farmer Angular/kalpavriksha-angular-v4/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Prashant/UserManagement/Farmer Angular/kalpavriksha-angular-v4/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Prashant/UserManagement/Farmer Angular/kalpavriksha-angular-v4/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Prashant/UserManagement/Farmer Angular/kalpavriksha-angular-v4/src/app/app.module.ts